# Limitar quantidade por tempo

Tags: php, timer

Como eu posso limitar um certo recurso no PHP para ser executado depois de um certo tempo definido por mim?

Exemplo:
Tenho um botão, clico nele e o mesmo envia 50 usuários para um campo chamado `count` na minha tabela, e também seto um tempo em um campo chamado `timer` no qual eu gostaria que fosse 20 minutos. E depois de 20 minutos ele reseta o count para 0 e o timer também volta a ser 0!

Eu já tive experiências com eventos no MySQL, porém não quero usar por motivos óbvios.

A minha tabela está assim:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_str` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `oauth_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `oauth_token_secret` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vip` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `days` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timer` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

Qual a lógica? o PHP fornece alguma função nativa para tal? Não quero usar `cookies` nem `sessions` por motivos de segurança quero que o `PHP` e o `MySQL` trabalhem ao meu favor.

Comment: Tem sim, existem 2 formas viáveis, a primeira é o uso de socket criando um "mini servidor" que sempre estará em execução e nele você seta as regras necessárias para resolver seu problema (mas nem toda hospedagem tem o prompt habilitado para uso então vamos para a segunda). Essa é a mais utilizada, crie um CROM no servidor para chamar uma página a cada X tempo, nessa página terão as regras que você vai fazer para verificar e tratar esses dados, o servidor vai executar essa página a cada X minutos. (Lembrando que o CROM só funciona em hospedagem)

Comment: Já li sobre o _CROM_ @GuilhermeBiancardi, é a melhor maneira até agora

Comment: Se você não necessita que o script execute em tempo real essa é a melhor forma de se fazer e a mais fácil de se implementar.