# Refêrencia função sleep PHP

Tags: php

Eu estou procurando uma forma de limitar o uso de um script por um determinado tempo, bom como disse em outra pergunta não quero usar `events` do MySQL.

Procurando, pesquisando, tentando fazer, encontrei isto na documentação, [sleep function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sleep.php)
Ela diz o seguinte:

> sleep — Atrasa a execução do script

Não está bem documentada ao meu ver, porém lá em baixo existem alguns [exemplos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sleep.php#105149) feitos por contribuidores.

Como realmente funciona esta função?

Obs: Está pergunta é diferente desta. [Limitar quantidade por tempo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255742/limitar-quantidade-por-tempo)

Comment: Como a própria documentação diz, a função *Sleep* atrasa a execução do script, veja esse [exemplo](https://repl.it/repls/IndigoEnchantingPrimate).

Comment: No caso eu poderia usar esta função _Sleep_ para limitar o uso de um botão?

Comment: Não, creio que o ideal seria ocultar esse botão pois essa função ela não vai impedir que o usuário clique novamente no botão.

Comment: Entendo, vou ver o que posso fazer, mas creio eu que ao clicar terei que esperar o tempo terminado por mim. Escondo o botão e ao terminar este tempo mostra-me novamente.

Comment: Sim, se estiver utilizando *Ajax* funcionara.

Comment: Sim vou utilizar ajax, aliás já estou fazendo;

Comment: O que não está escrito lá é que quase sempre que a função é usada está fazendo algo errado. Isto é pedir para tomar o ataque de DOS. E se quer mudar o comportamento de algo no cliente tem que mexer nele e não no servidor. Não que isto não possa ser burlado.

Comment: Pesquisa em cima de pesquisa cheguei a conclusão que o que o mineiro disse é verdade.

Comment: Uai brother, pq removeu a pergunta lá? Não deu certo?

Comment: @ÐvÐ, não deu aí pensei comigo, que ia acabar poluindo mas vou reabrir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sleep`, como diz a própria documentação, tem como finalidade atrasar o tempo da execução do script, a partir do ponto que a mesma é invocada.

Geralmente, usa-se a função `sleep` em loops infinitos, geralmente usado rodando em background em servidores, para executar determinada tarefa.

Por exemplo, se você precisa verificar de tempo em tempo se algo está pendente no banco de dados para poder processar esses dados através de um Webservice:

```
// Esse script está rodando pela linha de comando
// Laço (ou loop) infinito para executar uma verificação repetitiva

while (true) {


    $solicitacoes = Solicitacao::where('pendente', '=', 1)->get();

    foreach ($solicitacoes as $solicitacao) {
         $this->processarWebservice($solicitacao);

         $solicitacao->update(['pendente' => 0]);
    }

    sleep(60); // Determina que a próxima iteração sera feita daqui a 60 segundos
}
```

É raro o seu uso em HTTP, porém eu já pude contemplar uma implementação de [long polling](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254506/o-que-%C3%A9-long-polling) que usava `sleep` para retardar o tempo de consulta de dados.